# Multiple counts in one table UNINTENTIONALLY summing columns in rows

Tags: mysql, sql, count, mysql-workbench

I'm trying to get the number of hits for each day during a break to all show up in one table.

```
SELECT module, COUNT( * ) 
FROM mdl_log AS l
WHERE (FROM_UNIXTIME( l.`time` ) BETWEEN  '2014-12-16 00:00:00' AND '2014-12-17 00:00:00')
GROUP BY module
```

Gives me exactly what I need for one day (the 16th)

```
module  Count(*)
admin   11
assign  1
course  20
outcome 2
user    3
```

But when I try to get multiple days in the same table it give me a sum of the column in each row.

```
SELECT module 

 ,(SELECT COUNT( * ) 
FROM mdl_log as l
WHERE (FROM_UNIXTIME( l.`time` ) BETWEEN  '2014-12-12 00:00:00' AND '2014-12-13 00:00:00')
) AS "12/12/2014"

,(SELECT COUNT( * ) 
FROM mdl_log AS l
WHERE (FROM_UNIXTIME( l.`time` ) BETWEEN  '2014-12-16 00:00:00' AND '2014-12-17 00:00:00')
) AS "12/16/14"

FROM mdl_log 
group by module
```

This...

```
module 12/12/14  12/16/14
admin      1    37
assign     1    37
calendar   1    37
course     1    37
forum      1    37
grade      1    37
hsuforum   1    37
library    1    37
login      1    37
lti        1    37
message    1    37
outcome    1    37
question   1    37
quiz       1    37
role       1    37
url        1    37
user       1    37
webservice  1   37
workshop    1   37
```

Can you give me any advice on how to get this so it shows up how I want it?
e.g.

```
module  12/12/14  12/16/14
admin   1         11
assign  0         1
user    0         3
```

etc.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Apply the date criterion inside the `count` function:

```
SELECT module, 
COUNT(IF(FROM_UNIXTIME( l.`time` ) BETWEEN  '2014-12-12 00:00:00' AND '2014-12-13 00:00:00', 1, NULL) AS "12/12/2014",
COUNT(IF(FROM_UNIXTIME( l.`time` ) BETWEEN  '2014-12-16 00:00:00' AND '2014-12-17 00:00:00', 1, NULL) AS "12/16/2014"
FROM mdl_log 
group by module
```

Comment: Thank you, that's a big help